# How to find the Variance of a generalised function of random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose I have a function $f(x_1, \dots, x_N)$, where $x_i$'s are random variables. $x_i$'s have **SD** $\sigma_i$, and are all independent.

There are two additional assumptions, that $f$ is approximately linear within the range $x^{'}_i \pm \sigma_i$; and secondly $x_i$ and $x_j$ are uncorrelated for $i \ne j$.

> > How to find the **Var** of $f$?

Comment: If $f$ is approximately $\sum a_ix_i$ the the variance is approximately $\sum a_i^{2} \sigma_i^{2}$.

Comment: True. One question: You're throwing out the cross term expectation values since they are uncorrelated right?

Comment: Yes. Actually you also assumed independence of the $x_i$'s and this automatically implies that they are uncorrelated.

Comment: So is there a way to do this for a generic function $f$? Doing a Taylor expansion around $\sigma_i$ seems the way to go?

Comment: Taylor expansion around the origin, not $\sigma_i$.

Comment: If I assume $f$ is just a function of two random variables, i.e., $f(x_1, x_2)$ and then make a Taylor expansion around $(\sigma_1, \sigma_2)$, then the terms of $\mathcal{O}(x_i^2)$ and higher drops off as the function is approximately linear around $\sigma_i$. So one can thus calculate the variance. It turns out $\mathrm{Var} f(x_1, \dots, x_N)$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sigma_i^2 f_{x_i}(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_N)$. Is this correct?